# Ideals (one-sided ideals) of $n×n$ upper triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ideals

Is there any characterization of ideals (one-sided ideals) of $n\times n$ upper triangular matrices? I have just seen in monthly journal about $2 \times 2$ matrices in the below article
Left and Right Ideals in the Ring of $2 \times 2$ Matrices
Henryk Minc
The American Mathematical Monthly
Vol. 71, No. 1 (Jan., 1964), pp. 72-75

Comment: What are the entries of the matrices supposed to be: a field, a commutative ring, a general ring?